# How do you check for a specific game engine property with python? (2.7x only)

Tags: python, game-engine

Instead of having several ray sensors each set to look for a specific property, I would like to have one ray sensor that looks at everything and have python decide what to do with what is hit based on the property.

So something like this:

```
sensor = cont.sensors["Ray"]
if sensor.positive:
    trigger = sensor.hitObject
    if trigger.(whatever would determine if it has the property):
        # do something
    if trigger.(another property):
        # do something else
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
sensor = cont.sensors["Ray"]
if sensor.positive:
    trigger = sensor.hitObject
    if "property" in trigger:
        # do something
```

You may also want to check if the property exists and get it (all in one lookup), This can be done using `get` a fallback value to avoid `try/except`.

```
sensor = cont.sensors["Ray"]
if sensor.positive:
    trigger = sensor.hitObject
    prop = trigger.get("property", None)
    if prop is not None:
        # do something
```

This style of access is the same thats used in Python dictionaries. eg:

```
dct = {"a": 2}
if "a" in dct:
    print("found")

val = dct.get("b", 2)
print(val)  # -> 2 (or the value)
```